# Show only specific Tests or TestFixtures in NUNIT via a configuration file or another way

Tags: nunit, nunit-2.5

I have a bunch of NUNIT tests in several TestFixtures.  Currently, I just display all the tests for everyone.  Is there a way to hide some tests and/or test fixtures.  I have various "customers" and they don't all need to see every test.  For example, I have engineers using low level tests, and I have a QA department that is using higher level tests.  If I could have a configuration (XML?) file that I distributed with the dll that would be ideal.  Can someone point me to the documentation and example?  I did search the NUNIT site and did not see anything.

I am aware of the [IGNORE] attribute and I suppose a somewhat acceptable solution would be to have a configuration file that can apply IGNORE to various tests or testfixtures.  I'd hand out a different version of the configuration file to each customer. At least that way certain customers would not be able run certain tests.

I'm using version 2.5.5
Ideas?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Is it all in one big test dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - if the tests are in seperate assemblies, this can be accomplished by proper configuration of your NUnit projects.  However, this is not an option if the tests are in one large test assembly.  If this is the case, you may wish to break up the test assembly.  Here is the documentation on the NUnit ProjectEditor: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=projectEditor&r=2.2.10